# Is a blocking function on an asynchronous api idiomatic?

Tags: go, idioms

Is it more idiomatic to have an async api, with a blocking function as the synchronous api that simply calls the async api and waits for an answer before returning, rather than using a non-concurrent api and let the caller run it in their own goroutine if they want it async?

In my current case I have a worker goroutine that reads from a request channel and sends the return value down the response channel (that it got in a request struct from the request channel).

This seems to differ from the linked question since I need the return values, or to synchronize so that I can be sure the api call finishes before I do something else, to avoid race conditions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiomatic Golang goroutines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506013/idiomatic-golang-goroutines)

Comment: Well, that depends. Go is not narrow minded: Whatever suites your problem more is the "right" solution."

Answer (score -1):

For golang, I recommend [Effective Go-concurrency](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency). Especially I think everyone using golang need to known the basics of `goroutine` and `parallelization`:

Goroutines are multiplexed onto multiple OS threads so if one should block, such as while waiting for I/O, others continue to run. Their design hides many of the complexities of thread creation and management.

The current implementation of the Go runtime dedicates only a single core to user-level processing. An arbitrary number of goroutines can be blocked in system calls, but by default only one can be executing user-level code at any time.